# Simplifying a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, correlation

CODING IN PYTHON!

I am currently trying to create a correlation matrix. I have a matrix that is 14 by 1380. However, what I would like to do is extract certain values but I am having a hard time with it.

I would like a code of row 1 with values from columns 0-92, then row 2 values 93-185, in so on until for all the values. (ending with row 14 values 1286-1379).
Is there a way to code this that is easier than doing explicitly writing it out for each line of code?

Example something like: `matrix[:1, 0:92] + matrix[1:2,93:185]`

I was thinking a for loop but having a challenging time.

```
new_matrix = []
For m in matrix: 
    m[0:15, 0:93] # I would like to find a code that moves to the next row after 93 items, and continues 
    m.append(new_matrix)
```

Comment: Please include the codes you already wrote even if you're having a challenging time with it. It can be a wrong code or a wrong `for` loop but will help others to correct and simplify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have all your dimensions right. As currently phrased it sounds like you may have some off-by-one issues.

Would something like this work?

```py
matrix = [[...]...]
run_length = 92
result = [
    row[run_length * i : run_length * (i +2)]
    for (i, row) in matirx
]
```

There may be a simpler way of expressing this, or maybe you need something more complicated for your task. I'm not sure if I've understood your problem correctly.

Generally I would advocate against using an explicit loop for deriving one list/matrix/etc from another.